# Read HTTP output using shell/bash script

Tags: http, bash, shell, response

My url (http://myhost.com/getuser/Default.aspx?username=**b772643**) returns the following line of of info always:

```
John, Thomas;John.B.Thomas@Company.com
```

I wish to read this line using a shell or bash script without wget/lynx.  I'm in a situation where I cannot use any other utility, the perl language etc.

Comment: just verified. i can use curl

Answer (score 24):

Curl or wget are obviously better for the job but for the record bash and Unix standard commands (cat & printf) can do the job.

ksh introduced shell network internal handling and this has been adopted by bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 5<> /dev/tcp/myhost.com/80
cat <&5 &
printf "GET /getuser/Default.aspx?username=b772643 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" >&5
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in one line?

Comment: @ethree Sure, just put all commands , semi-colon separated, in a single line. You might also create a shell function.

Comment: @ethree Please define "isn't very happy" in more technical and descriptive terms.

Comment: Well, I think it's getting upset about the &'s. -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'

Comment: @ethree You probably put too much semicolons, please post the line you have issues with, that one works fine with me: `(exec 5<> /dev/tcp/www.google.com/80;cat <&5 &;printf "GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" >&5)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61915/discussion-between-ethree-and-jlliagre).

Answer (score 5):

One liner:

```
(echo 'GET /getuser/Default.aspx?username=b772643' > /dev/tcp/myhost.com/80);
```

Answer (score 3):

so

```
curl "http://myhost.com/getuser/Default.aspx?username=b772643"


curl "http://myhost.com/getuser/Default.aspx?username=b772643"| sed 's/\(.*\);\(.*\)/\2 \1/' | while read email name; do echo =$email=$name=; done
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone. all solution works good. 

Curl is best one 

curl "http://myhost.com/getuser/Default.aspx?username=b772643"

Answer (score 3):

You could use :

```
curl "http://myhost.com/getuser/Default.aspx?username=b772643"
```

and extract the datas from what is returned :)